# Php - update + ou - no campo

Tags: php

Tenho criada uma db com

```
             Nome produto |  stock

                 Rato                     3
```

O meu objetivo e.. quando inserir o numero no input ele que veja se é positivo(1) ou negativo(-1) e depois faz o update do genero “stock = stock + 1, ou stock = stock -1.

Como faco isso usando input?..

Comment: Voces as veses irritam.. nada doque disseram e uma possivel ajuda.. eu quero que o php verifique se o input number e negativo ou positivo... para depois dar entrada no update de forma certa dass

Comment: Não entendi sua revolta. Você pediu que o update fosse na forma stock = stock + 1 e é exatamente a forma que foi explicada na pergunta citada. Você chegou a abrir o link? Sobre identificar positivo e negativo será desnecessário uma vez que se você somar um valor negativo é o mesmo que subtrair. Matemática básica. Se após estudar o material citado ainda lhe restar alguma dúvida, peço que edite sua pergunta e esclareça melhor o que ainda lhe falta para concluir.

Answer (score 0):

Vamos lá João! acredito que o que você procura é bem simples, vou tentar ser o mais didatico possivel.

**1° Parte (Input)**

```
<form type="post" action="NOMEDAPAGINA.php"> //POST pega o valor e ACTION manda pra pagina do PHP
<input name="n1" type="number"> //input
</form>
```

**2° Parte (Pegando do Valores)**

```
$n1 = isset($_POST['n1'])?$_POST['n1']:0; // $n1 = SE TIVER VALOR "do input n1" PEGUE "valor input n1" SENÃO "valor vai ser 0"; 
$stock = mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT nome_do_campo FROM nome_da_tabela WHERE cd_do_registro"); //Pega o valor do stock no banco de dados
$array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($stock); //joga o valor para uma variavel
```

**3° Parte (Condição)**

```
if ($n1 < 0){ //Se for negativo 
$total = $array['stock'] - 1; //Retira -1 do stock
mysqli_query($Conexao, "UPDATE Nome_da_tabela SET Nome_do_Campo ='$total' WHERE cd_do_registro"); //Muda valor no banco
} else { //Se for positivo
$total = $array['stock'] + 1; //soma +1 do stock
mysqli_query($Conexao, "UPDATE Nome_da_tabela SET Nome_do_Campo ='$total' WHERE cd_do_registro"); //Muda valor no banco
}
```

Espero ter ajudado ! Boa sorte.